# When I sign in with SignInAsync in ASP.NET Core Identity, RedirectToLocal is not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

When I sign in with SignInAsync in ASP.NET Core Identity, RedirectToLocal is not authenticated.

If I log in without returning Url or go to allow anonymous action, it works fine, but when I redirect authenticate action return to the login page like the user never signs in. Still, I go to allow anonymous action and see the user sign in everything is okay.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWithSms(string userId, string code, string returnUrl)
{
    if (userId == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userId));
    }

    if (code == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(code));
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(ErrorConstant.UnableToLoadUser, userId));
    }

    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return View("AccountError", this.GetErrorVm(AccountConstant.Persian.ConfirmSms, ErrorConstant.Persian.CodeWrong));
    }

    if (!user.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
    {
        user.PhoneNumberConfirmed = true;
        _context.Users.Update(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

    await _setUserActivityLog.SetLogAsync(user.Id, AccountConstant.Persian.LoginToProfile);

    return RedirectToLocal(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? AccountConstant.Routes.ReturnUrlManageIndex : returnUrl);
}
```

redirect action:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionDetail(menuCode: MenuConstant.ManageService.Code, name: "پاسخ دادن به تیکت")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TicketAnswer(long id)
{
    var baseTicket = await _context.Tickets.Include(t => t.TicketType).Include(t => t.TicketRecords)
        .ThenInclude(tr => tr.Person)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
    if (baseTicket == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var vm = new ManageVm<TicketAnwserVm>
    {
        Entity = new TicketAnwserVm
        {
            QuickResponses = _context.QuickResponses.OrderBy(qr => qr.Title).Select(qr => new QuickResponseVm
            {
                Id = qr.Id,
                Title = qr.Title
            }),
            Ticket = new TicketDisplayVm(baseTicket.StartDate)
            {
                Id = baseTicket.Id,
                PersonId = baseTicket.PersonId,
                State = baseTicket.State,
                Subject = baseTicket.Subject,
                TicketTypeName = baseTicket.TicketType.Name,
                TicketRecords = baseTicket.TicketRecords.Join(_context.Users, tr => tr.PersonId,
                    u => u.PersonId,
                    (tr, u) => new TicketRecordVm(tr.Date)
                    {
                        Id = tr.Id,
                        PersonName = tr.Person.Name,
                        UserId = u.Id,
                        Content = tr.Content,
                        IsOwner = tr.IsOwner,
                        TicketId = tr.TicketId,
                        Status = tr.IsOwner ? TicketStatus.Out : TicketStatus.In
                    })
            }
        }
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: `when I redirect authenticate action return to the login page like the user never signs in`Can you share the action you redirect to?

Comment: @YiyiYou Hi, I add it in question.